# Spark Pipeline - Chain Regressors Together

Tags: regression, neural-networks, python, scikit-learn, spark-mllib

I'm running this on databricks, using python, spark, pipeline, mlflow, etc. Can use whichever library I need to though

I have a simple Linear Regression script. I separately have a Random Forest script.

The data set has 10 features and 1 label to predict. All columns are normalized doubles.

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=in_cols, outputCols='features')
rf = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol='label')
#lr = LinearRegression(labelCol='label', featuresCol='features')
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol='label', predictionCol='prediction', metricName='r2')
stages = [assebler, rf]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=3, seed=42..)
cv.fit(train).transform(test)
```

How can I have the random forest output be a vector and feed its output into the linear regression and have the model fit. Similar to how a neural network layer's output would be the input to the next layer.

I'm aware this isn't really the ideal model, but want to know how it can be done